# swagger ui is not available for jhipster application which has no client

Tags: swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I created a jhipster application which has now client. the initial configuration is options are given below,

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? nouisample
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? No
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) No cache - Warning, when using an SQL database, this will
disable the Hibernate 2nd level cache!
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which other technologies would you like to use? API first development using OpenAPI-generator
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? No client
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use?
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

I starter the application in the below profiles,

```
2023-06-18T15:15:58.305+05:30  INFO 23300 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.myapp.NouisampleApp        : The following 2 profiles are active: "dev", "api-docs"
```

the application starter in " http://localhost:8080/".

but i am not able to connect the swagger ui. i tried the following urls,

1. http://localhost:8080/#/docs
2. http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
3. http://127.0.0.1:8761/swagger-ui/index.html

All i am getting is an error page with following text.

```
Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: Not Found
```

can anyone help? How can i access the swagger ui?

Comment: You have to choose a client in order to have a Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt Raible says you can't see Swagger UI because you don't have any client, as a possible solution you can access http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs or http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml where you can download a yaml to import in postman or similar. This works at least for jhipster 7.9.4, but I think it works from at least 7.5.x.

Hope this helps.